# Combine generic types where T implements List

Tags: c#, generics

I have a collection of DTOs and container DTOs e.g., `BankDetails` and containing DTO `ListOfBankDetails : List<BankDetails>`.

I have a generic network method that *can* return multiple container DTOs as ApiResults and needs to combine them into 1 ApiResult (but T is not always a list). The MergeResult member of the ApiResult class combines it with another ApiResult, where T is a DTO collection, e.g., `ListOfBankDetails`.

```
public class ApiResult<T>
{
    public T Response { get; set; }

    public void MergeResult(ApiResult<T> toMerge)
    {
        if (Response != null && toMerge.Response != null)
        {
            (Response as List<object>).AddRange(toMerge.Response as List<object>);
        }
    }
}
```

However (Response as List) returns null. I have also tried the below, but the cast to (T) after the Concat operation fails.

```
public void MergeResult(ApiResult<T> toMerge)
{
    if (Response != null && toMerge.Response != null)
    {
        Response = (T)((Response as IEnumerable<object>).Concat(toMerge.Response as IEnumerable<object>));
    }
}
```

How do I combine 2 generic types if they are implementing List?

Comment: You seem to have left out some important details, e.g. the definition of `Response` and the definition of `ApiResult<>`. Can I assume that `ApiResult<T>` has a `Response` property as well, and that `ApiResult<T>.Response` is the same type as `this.Response` in your example? Or can they be different types? What types are they? Can you add those details to your question?

Comment: Hi @JohnWu good point I have added those in now.

Comment: The problem appears to be that you're casting a `List<BankDetails>` to a `List<object>` before trying to add to it. The cast is disallowed because you lose specificity in the contained type. John's proposal should solve that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the ability to merge won't work for all types of `T`. So the `MergeResult` method doesn't belong to to this class really. It belongs to a subtype, where `T` is a list.

```
public class ApiListResult<T> : ApiResult<List<T>>
{
    public void MergeResult(ApiListResult<T> toMerge)
    {
        this.Response.AddRange(toMerge.Response);
    }
}
```

Since this code is type-safe the merging code is very trivial to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Response is IList responseAsIList && toMerge.Response is IList toMergeResponseAsIList)
{
    foreach (var item in toMergeResponseAsIList)
    {
        responseAsIList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should spend some time explaining your answer instead of dumping code.